# Proof involving matrix equation

Tags: linear-algebra

$A$ and $B$ are $(n\times n)$ matrices and $AB + B + A = 0$. Prove that then $AB=BA$.

How should I approach this problem?

Answer (score 10):

Adding the identity matrix $I$ on both sides, we find $(A+I)(B+I) = I$. Hence $A+I$ and $B+I$ are inverses of each other. It follows that $(B+I)(A+I) = I$ as well. Expanding gives $BA + B + A = 0$, hence $AB = BA$.

Comment: As a side note, interestingly if $A_{n\times n}$ and $B_{n\times n}$ follow $AB+B+A=\mathbf{0}$ and $\det A\neq 0\wedge \det B\neq 0$ then:$$A^{-1}+B^{-1}=-\mathbb{I}$$