# Suppose that matric $AB+A+B=0$, how to prove that $AB=BA$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-equations, matrix-calculus

Assume that $A$ and $B$ and $n\times n$ matrices, and 
$$
AB+A+B=0.
$$
How can we prove that $AB=BA$?

Thank you in advance. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: I answered this question this week: 
http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/702256/proof-involving-matrix-equation/702257.

Comment: You can view this as "completing the rectangle" where the term you add to complete it happens to be convenient ($I$).

Answer (score 6):

If 
$$
A+B+AB=0, \tag{1}
$$
then
$$
(I+A)(I+B)=I+A+B+AB=I,
$$
and hence $I+A$ is the inverse of $I+B$, which implies that
$$
I=(I+B)(I+A)=I+B+A+BA,
$$
or
$$
A+B+BA=0. \tag{2}
$$
Combination of $(1)$ and $(2)$ provides that
$$
AB=BA.
$$

Comment: Suppose you didn't have the happy idea of considering $(I+A)(I+B)$. What might lead you to this idea?

Comment: $A+B+AB$ looks like $(I+A)(I+B)$ with $I$ missing!

Comment: Moreover $A$ (resp. $B$) is a polynomial in $B$ (resp. in $A$).

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

$$0=AB+A+B=(A+I)(B+I)-I \implies (B+I)(A+I)=I\;\;\text{(why?)}$$

and we're almost done since

$$(B+I)(A+I)=I\implies BA+B+A=0\ldots$$